# React Navigation Animated Switching Navigator blinks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I've got a question about React Navigation Switch Navigator.

I created a bottom navigator with an animated switch Navigator on my own. The structure is like this.

```
class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* A content */
    )
  }
}

const B = createStackNavigator({
  b1: {screen: B1},
  b2: {screen: B2}
})

const BottomNav = createAnimatedSwitchNavigator({
  a: {screen: A},
  b: {screen: B}
},{
  /* transition config */
})
```

When I implemented this on Android devices, it blinked with black and then the next screen faded in when I navigated from B to A, while it worked fine when I navigated from A to B. But what I want is to navigate with the previous screen fading out and the next screen fading in.
Trying to change the structure, I noticed that when I navigate from a stack navigator screen, it blinks for a moment.

It works fine on iOS devices.

I also tried in vain to solve this by creating React Component with the stack navigator.

```
const BNav = createStackNavigator({
  b1: { screen: B1 },
  b2: { screen: B2 },
});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(BNav);
class B extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AppContainer />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Below are the versions of the libraries.

```
"react-navigation": "4.3.9",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "2.5.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.0",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "1.8.0",
"react-navigation-animated-switch": "0.5.12",
```

Is this a bug? If so, where can I report this?

Thank you for reading.